# Superblock error, but no clue what's the reason

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I know this issue is not new, and there're a lot of threads already talking about it, and most of them are actually solved.

The difference in this problem is that I've tried everything and still no clue what could be the main reason or source for this problem.

I've 10 IBM servers, only 4 of them had this issue which I am about to explain.
I am setting up auto-decrypted partition at boot time, environment is Linux CentOS, same process every time, using **luks**, these are the steps I take usually (and it works with some machines):

1- luksFormat the partition

2- luksOpen the partition

3- dd a new key file

4- luksAddKey key file

5- make the file system *mskf.ext4*

6- add *fstab* entry

7- add *cryttab* entry

8- mount all

in all cases, those steps worked fine, and the mount was successful! but in some cases (4 out of 10), after rebooting the server, there will be superblock issues, and the server won't boot unless I remove *fstab* entry.

What could be the problem, I am guessing it must have something to do with the harddisk itself, but I don't think some bad sector or something because it's not logical that 4 out of 10 have bad sectors!!
My guess is that I am missing something in the partitioning table maybe, I really have no clues what is happening here.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It might help to post the fstab entry?

Comment: I've found the reason and fixed it, I'll update the thread with an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simply formatting the hard disk, clearing the *msdos* table and recreating *GPT* table again, I don't know technically what happened so if you have any idea about it or maybe some links about why this fix worked please share it here.

I used **GParted** (from *Ubuntu* live distro) to do the previously mentioned, restarted and installed the system again, everything worked perfectly.